# jQuery - chaining events to execute function

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to execute a function, if any of multiple events happen. Right now, I'm trying to make it execute on change, and on keydown. The first code works, the next two do not (when I add the second event.)

How should I write it? Thanks.

This works:

```
$("#userCreation").change(function(){ 
    userValidate();
});
```

---

These do not:

```
$("#userCreation").change(function().keydown(function(){
    userValidate();
}));
```

---

```
$("#userCreation").change.keydown(function(){
    userValidate();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can execute the same code for multiple events using `.on`:

```
$("#userCreation").on('change keydown', function(){ 
    userValidate();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some syntax errors; you should try:

```
$("#userCreation").change(function(){ 
    userValidate();
}).keydown(function(){
    userValidate();
});
```

Or, ideally:

```
$('userCreation').on('change keydown', userValidate);
```

The `on()` method accepts a white-space separated string of event-names, each of which will, in response, trigger the function passed as the second parameter.

This:

```
$("#userCreation").change(function().keydown(function(){
    userValidate();
}));
```

doesn't work because you're apparently trying to chain the `keydown` event-handling method to the anonymous function of the `change()` method; and results in the error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

```
$("#userCreation").change.keydown(function(){
    userValidate();
});
```

Doesn't work because you're trying to chain the keydown method to the (nonexistant) change property of jQuery object returned by the selector; resulting in:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

References:

- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 0):

$("#userCreation").change(function(){ //do stuff }).keydown(function(){ // do stuff });